# Помогите отрисовать бинарное дерево

Tags: javascript, html, json, html5, binary

Не работал с json форматами и подобным, задание отрисовать дерево бинарное c входными данными типа

```
{
  data: { id: 'a', name: 'q', left: true, right: false }
},
{
  data: { id: 'b', name: 'w', left: false, right: true }
},
```

как то так, в задании формат подачи данных не указан, может быть в любом виде не обязательно в json, можно и js объектами.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

выйти должно такое, но не обязательно все это сильно верстать, буду рад если подкинете логику, я постараюсь доделать

Comment: знать бы ещё что значат эти лефт райт и где древовидный формат в самомих приведенных объектах ...

Comment: @MedvedevDev Так там может быть что угодно,я просто думал, что лефт райт - это куда будет идти направление и тд, просто я не могу понять как это реализовать, вот по этому и спросил тут

Comment: от формата данных зависит большая часть решения задачи ... ваш приведенный вариант и структура скажем `[ [ [] [] ] [ [] [] ] ]` - совсем разные вещи

Comment: @MedvedevDev я всего лишь сказал, как я представляю, так как я не знаю, как это сделать лучше и вообще как это сделать, я и пришел на so

Comment: _"не обязательно в json, можно и js объектами"_ - джейсон это и есть js-объект :) Точнее, форма его представления.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Набросал примерный вариант на флексбоксах.
С линиями - надеюсь, самостоятельно разберетесь :) Там нужно применять через трансформ повороты, транслейт, и прочую жуть... в которой я далеко не спец.

```js
const $d = document;

function addNodeFromObj(obj, parentEl = $d.body) {
  let el = $d.createElement('div');
  el.classList.add('node');
  if (!obj) {
    el.classList.add('leaf');
    parentEl.appendChild(el);
    return;
  }
  el.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
    <span class="name">${obj.name}</span><div class="container"></div>
  `);
  parentEl.appendChild(el);
  if (obj.left || obj.right) {
    el = el.querySelector('.container');
    addNodeFromObj(obj.left, el);
    addNodeFromObj(obj.right, el);
  }
  else
    el.classList.add('leaf');
}

let tree = {
  name: '1',
  left: {
    name: '2',
    left : { name: '4' },
    right: { name: '5' }
  },
  right: {
    name: '3',
    left : { name: 'x' },
    right: { name: 'y' }
  }
};
addNodeFromObj(tree);
```

```css
html, 
body {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  font: 16px sans-serif;
}

.node {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 1 45%;
  text-align: center; line-height: 2em;
}
.node:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 50.5%; height: calc(40px + 2em);
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 20px);
  border: 1px solid #000; border-bottom: none;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 100% 100% 0 0;
}
.node.leaf:before { border: none; }
body > .node { width: 100%; margin-top: 20px; }

.node .container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap; justify-content: center;
  margin: 2em 0;
}

.node > span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2em; height: 2em;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000; border-radius: 50%;
}
```

**upd.:**

- Поправил стили линий, теперь линии не должны вылезать за нижнюю границу кружков дочерних узлов.
- Исправлено неправильное позиционирование узлов без соседей.